# how to connect to specific schema with param: connection_factory in psycopy2 in python?

Tags: psycopg2

I already have the demo how to connect to specific schema with psycopg2 like :

```
psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", 
                 port="5432", 
                 user="postgres", 
                 password="password", 
                 database="database", 
                 options="-c search_path=dbo,public")
```

I readed the pyscopg2 documents, there is another way for connection: using param: connection_factory , but searched a lot without any demo, who can give me a demo how to connect to specific schema with this param in psycopg2?
I tried: (I want to connect "myschema")

```
connection_info = {'database': 'postgres', 
                   'host': '127.0.0.1', 
                    'port': 5432, 
                   'user': 'postgres', 
                     'password': 'postgres', 
                   'sslmode': 'prefer', 
                   'options': '-c search_path=myschema,public'}
conn_factory = psycopg2.extensions.connection
psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=conn_factory, **connection_info )
```

but failed.

Comment: See [Connection and cursor factories](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#subclassing-connection). You have to create a subclass of `psycopg2.extensions.connection` and then use that subclass as the `connection_factory` argument. The example at the link is for a cursor factory, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

```
connection_info = {'database': 'postgres', 
                   'host': '127.0.0.1', 
                    'port': 5432, 
                   'user': 'postgres', 
                     'password': 'postgres', 
                   'sslmode': 'prefer', 
                   'options': '-c search_path=myschema,public'}
```

this should be ok

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I think what the OP is trying to say is they chose not to use a connection factory.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**